# How to validate value of bit in byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a byte array, for example 400 bytes.... and then a position of a bit, for example 6. How can I check if the value of this bit is 1? So in my example, the return value will be true.

example:

```
final byte[] b = new byte[] { 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

what is 00000100....
pos = 6
result  = true

Comment: I can't understand the question

Comment: `if (b[position] == 1) return true;`

Comment: Are you sure you should not use a BitSet, which is precisely suited to the task you're trying to accomplish? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: Oli: nothing DANDY: you are wrong because b[6] return 0 not 1JB Nizet nope I have to use byte

Comment: keyser ? What is incomprehensible ?

Comment: `if((number & 4) > 0) return true`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you count your bits like this:

Bit 1 is the highest bit of the first byte, bit 8 is the lowest bit of the first byte, bit 9 is the highest byte of the second byte and so on.

Then you can use:

```
private boolean isSet(int index) {
    int bitIndex = (index-1) % 8;
    int byteIndex = (index-1) / 8;
    int bitMask = 1 << 7-bitIndex;
    return (b[byteIndex] & bitMask) > 0; 
}
```

However, if you used (for me) a more natural way to index so that bit 0 was the lowest bit in the first byte, bit 7 the highest bit of the first byte, bit 8 the lowest but of the second byte (and  so on) the the could would be:

```
private boolean isSet(int index) {
    int bitIndex = index % 8;
    int byteIndex = index / 8;
    int bitMask = 1 << bitIndex;
    return (b[byteIndex] & bitMask) > 0; 
}
```

Comment: thx a lot it work I know that I count it vice versa because it is business requirement

Answer (score 0):

Since you count positions in the byte and in the Array backwards:

```
public boolean bitAtPos (byte [] b, int pos) {
  int el = b[pos/8];
  return ((el >> (8-(pos%8)) & 1) == 1);
}
```

Comment: hm but your last row return int not boolean

Comment: your answer is correct thx a lot. you just forget to compare this int with 1

Comment: hm so ry but your answer isnt correct too because when I have in byte array negative number as -128 what is 10000000 then this method doesnt work

Comment: @hudi: Yes, I'm sorry, I was in a hurry. Corrected the bit-test.

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean validateValue(byte[] array, int numberToValidate, int position) {
    return (array.length > position-1 && position >= 1) ? array[position-1] == numberToValidate : false;
}
```

This method helps you use it multiple time for any number you want to validate.
Note: I added some pre-validation:
if you use an invalid position as a parameter it will return false. Best practice would be to throw an exception but I'll you deal with that.

Comment: sorry but this answer is wrong because position is position of bit not byte. in my example b[5] return 0 not 1 as you expected

Comment: Nevermind, I finally understood your question. Try stating you question better next time...

Comment: because b = 4,0,0,0,0,.. so b[5] = 0